# Kqueue udata field changing

Tags: c, macos, unix, libc, kqueue

On mac I am using kqueue, it states that udata is unchanged. However the array returned in `event_data` of `kevent` call is being modified somewhat. What could cause this? I am passing in the pointer to string casted to void*, and when i read after `kevent` after the first 3 characters the rest are coming out modified.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel only saves and returns the value of the pointer itself, not the contents of the memory it points to. Chances are that you're passing a pointer to memory that is being overwritten later on.

The `kqueue64()` system call is a little bit more explicit about this by defining the field as a `uint64_t`.

Comment: Thanks for that! I'll mess with it a bit more :)